# How to install Openscad in Ubuntu 18.04/18.10?

Tags: 18.04, 18.10

There is no current release of this source package in 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).
However, `openscad-mcad` exists, which depends on `openscad`, so that's obviously an error.

Comment: Why is the dependency obviously an error?

Comment: 18.04 is now supported, the package is still missing (with an open bug report), and the question/answer should now be valid.

Comment: The package exists in a ppa as described [here](https://alexjoz.gitbooks.io/code-life/content/chapter1.html)

Comment: There's a snap here that I can confirm works for Ubuntu 18.04: https://snapcraft.io/openscad

Answer (score 10):

It seems openscad is neither in 18.04 nor in 18.10, I just opened a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openscad/+bug/1766555), feel free to subscribe to it.

In the meantime, here is a procedure to install openscad from the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openscad/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openscad
```

Comment: Doesn't work on my Kubuntu 18.04. Apt install complains with this error:  `openscad : Depends: libqt5scintilla2-12v5`. This lib is supposed to be in the universe repo, but doesn't appear to be there either.

Answer (score 3):

### In Ubuntu 18.10

For this Ubuntu release, OpenSCAD is neither in the official repos nor in the `ppa:openscad/releases` PPA ([see?](http://ppa.launchpad.net/openscad/releases/ubuntu/dists/)). Installing the [nightly build as a Snap package](https://snapcraft.io/openscad-nightly) is a viable short-term alternative:

```
sudo snap install openscad-nightly
```

**Using libraries in the OpenSCAD Snap:** Like any OpenSCAD installation, it comes with one bundled library of CAD functions that you can use out of the box. You would use `include <….scad>` statements with paths relative to the [installation library location](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Libraries#Library_Locations), which is here:

```
/snap/openscad-nightly/current/usr/share/openscad-nightly/libraries/
```

Since this is only meant for libraries bundled with OpenSCAD and Snap installation directories are not writable anyway, you would install other libraries manually into the built-in library location, which for the Snap package is this:

```
$HOME/snap/openscad-nightly/current/.local/share/OpenSCAD/libraries
```

You can also set a "nicer" user-defined library location via `$OPENSCADPATH`.

### In Ubuntu 19.04

The good news is that starting with this Ubuntu release, the brand new version OpenSCAD 2019.01~RC2-2 will be in the official Ubuntu repositories ([see](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/openscad)). Then, installation will be easy and disk space saving again:

```
sudo apt install openscad
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast workaround for desperate/non-technical users or the trial-minded is suggested [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openscad/+bug/1766555/comments/24) by user glenstewart:

```
I suggest to just use the AppImage provided on the scad download page. The 
latest build at the moment, is OpenSCAD-2019.01-RC3.1-x86_64.AppImage

Just chmod 755 it, and then run. Much easier than all the fuss listed 
above. Runs fine for me on Ubuntu 18.04.
```

This worked for me as well on Ubuntu 18.04.5, when I downloaded `OpenSCAD-2019.05-x86_64.AppImage`.
Download page [here](http://www.openscad.org/downloads.html#linux), look under "Other Linux" for the `.AppImage` download.

(Thanks to @pim for the link to the bug and associated discussion.)